# Как в git при клонировании сразу зайти в папку и в ветку?

Tags: git

Например пишем `git clone https://github.com/имя/имя-файла.git`,
потом нужно написать `cd` в нее, потом `git checkout` имя-ветки

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

например:

```
$ git clone --branch ветка url-хранилища .
```

- `--branch ветка` — после клонирования будет выполнена команда `checkout` именно на эту ветку, а не на ту, что указана в удалённом хранилище меткой `HEAD`.
- `.` (точка) — текущий каталог. должен быть пуст.

оба условия выполнены: по окончании клонирования вы увидите в текущем каталоге развёрнутую рабочую копию хранилища, причём текущей будет указанная вами ветка.